# AppStore Different App Icon and Name

Tags: ios, icons, app-store

I was wondering, how can i have a specific app icon on the AppStore and have a different App Icon once the app has been downloaded?

For example, if you look for "Spy Calc" in the AppStore it has the icon of a calculator and a spy, although, once you download it, you only see the icon with a calculator.

How are they doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app icon (that appear in your iphone installation) is stored inside your assets catalog and the icon in the App Store is saved in itunesConnect. Maybe you forgot update in itunesconnect your app icon (i made this mistake once)